# ArrayList is Empty in HashMap

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have the following code. 
Why items in hashMap is empty after execute items.clear?
how I can keep data in items in HashMap ?

```
Class itemCategory{
   String name;
   List<itemCategory> items= new ArrayList<itemCategory>();
}

Map<String, Object> CategoryItems= new HashMap<>();
List<itemCategory> items= new ArrayList<itemCategory>();
List<String> names= new ArrayList<String>();
for ( String name: names) {
   items.getAllitems(name); 
   CategoryItems.put(name,items)
   items.clear
}
```

Comment: what are you doing you have no data and you are iterating over it which is obviously empty.

Comment: you need to add data into your names list first...... its currently empty

Comment: sorry, your code does not make any sence.

Comment: @dit very helpful.

Comment: @DroiDev the code does not compile. There is no method `ArrayList#getAllitems`. I would help, but need more legal code.

Comment: you dont need to compile his code to tell him what he is missing. you 'should' be able to look at it and right away know whats wrong.

Comment: Guys, Please look to my idea, the code is not similar what I really have, if I sent the real code you will be confused as there is a lot of the code not related to what I am ask about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue is Solved:

I changed ArrayList in HashMap to name+id as a key and itemCategory as data

I found that ArrayList is linked to ArrayList in HashMap, so if you do any operation on it will be reflected to ArrayList in HashMap.

Answer (score 1):

- When you are initalizing your array `List<itemCategory> items= new ArrayList<itemCategory>();` it's an empty array
- You need to add items to your List
- You can only add instances of `itemCategory`
- You can add to **List** `items.add(new itemCategory())`
- You can also initialize the `List` as follows:

  ```
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {{
  add(new itemCategory());
  add(new itemCategory());
  add(new itemCategory());
  }};
  ```
- Now you can add the items in the **HashMap**
- But if you use `items.clear()` inside the for loop than list contents will clear and you will only store a single item in your hashmap
- If you do not want the content of `items` then make `items.clear()` outside the for loop

Comment: the issue is that after execute items.clear() the hasMap CategoryItems.put(name,items) will have its items empty

Comment: Does your List  `items` have any data in it?? Does your List `names` have any data in it